# Unable to connect to host www.springframework.org

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring

Hi i am trying to build my web application through Eclipse. In one of the xml file, I have the following line.

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
```

When build is done in Eclipse, i am getting the error **"Unable to connect to host www.springframework.org"**

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Could you please anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.coderanch.com/t/518066/Spring/Spring-mvc-DOCTYPE-dtd-validation

Answer (score 0):

There is [an outage at the moment](https://twitter.com/springops/status/463942426214686720) but you should never get those files from the web. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version/20900801#20900801) for more details

Follow [@springops](https://twitter.com/springops) for a follow-up of this issue

Answer (score 0):

`!DOCTYPE`-directives give an XML parser a .dtd-file which shows how to parse the current code.

When eclipse's XML-parser reads the file it tries to get the definition file (.dtd) from www.springframework.org, but it can't connect, therefore it throws this error.

<strike>The URL works so the error is at your internet connection. Check your proxy settings, firewall etc; but it's not important so you can safely ignore this error.</strike> It just worked for me right now; see edit.

EDIT: According to the comments this is a temporary issue of the server, just ignore the error ;)