# default XSD schema location beans / context

Tags: spring, xsd

to me it looks like the default XSD (without a version number) for beans and context has disappeared. If I visit http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/ or  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/ the unnumbered version is not there any more. Is this temporally or are 'we' supposed to use the numbered version(s) from now on?

Regards,
Tjeerd.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20900801/3630157) can help you... It seems that there is no need to report it... I hope this helps you out if so, mark this as response, thank you..

```
It is recommended to use the "versionless" XSDs, because they're 
mapped to the current version of the framework you're using in your application.
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I was using the "versionless" schema until today. Now I switch to a versioned (3.2) schema, so I'm able to "run" the code again. (it was failing with a XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException)

Comment: Good...If you can to set this as the right answer it would be pretty good... Thank you...