# Webservice with Gson in Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, gson

I would like to use Gson for webservices in spring 4. I followed [steps](http://bitfish.eu/java-ee/spring-webservice-gson/) in this tutorial.

**SocialGraphUI-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="socialgraphui.controller" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

   <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/styles/" />
   <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter" />
        <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

</beans>
```

**GsonMessageConverter.java**

```
public class GsonMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object>
        implements GenericHttpMessageConverter<Object> {
    public static final Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    private Gson _gson;
    private Type _type = null;
    private boolean _prefixJson = false;

    /**
     * Construct a new {@code GsonMessageConverter} with a default
     * {@link Gson#Gson() Gson}.
     */
    public GsonMessageConverter() {
        this(new Gson());
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new {@code GsonMessageConverter}.
     * 
     * @param serializeNulls
     *            true to generate json for null values
     */
    public GsonMessageConverter(boolean serializeNulls) {
        this(serializeNulls ? new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()
                : new Gson());
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new {@code GsonMessageConverter}.
     * 
     * @param gson
     *            a customized {@link Gson#Gson() Gson}
     */
    public GsonMessageConverter(Gson gson) {
        super(new MediaType("application", "json", DEFAULT_CHARSET));
        setGson(gson);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the {@code Gson} for this view. If not set, a default
     * {@link Gson#Gson() Gson} is used.
     * <p>
     * Setting a custom-configured {@code Gson} is one way to take further
     * control of the JSON serialization process.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if gson is null
     */
    public void setGson(Gson gson) {
        Assert.notNull(gson, "'gson' must not be null");
        _gson = gson;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this._type = type;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return _type;
    }

    /**
     * Indicates whether the JSON output by this view should be prefixed with
     * "{} &&". Default is false.
     * <p>
     * Prefixing the JSON string in this manner is used to help prevent JSON
     * Hijacking. The prefix renders the string syntactically invalid as a
     * script so that it cannot be hijacked. This prefix does not affect the
     * evaluation of JSON, but if JSON validation is performed on the string,
     * the prefix would need to be ignored.
     */
    public void setPrefixJson(boolean prefixJson) {
        this._prefixJson = prefixJson;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return canRead(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, MediaType mediaType) {
        return canRead(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return canWrite(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        // should not be called, since we override canRead/Write instead
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * Generic types will be processed here.
     */
    @Override
    public Object read(Type type, Class<?> contextClass,
            HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws HttpMessageNotReadableException, IOException {
        setType(type);
        return readInternal(null, inputMessage);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {

        Reader json = new InputStreamReader(inputMessage.getBody(),
                getCharset(inputMessage.getHeaders()));

        try {
            Type typeOfT = getType();
            if (typeOfT != null) {
                return _gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT);
            } else {
                return _gson.fromJson(json, clazz);
            }
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException ex) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Could not read JSON: "
                    + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (JsonIOException ex) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Could not read JSON: "
                    + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (JsonParseException ex) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Could not read JSON: "
                    + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } finally {
            setType(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object o, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                outputMessage.getBody(), getCharset(outputMessage.getHeaders()));

        try {
            if (this._prefixJson) {
                writer.append("{} && ");
            }
            Type typeOfSrc = getType();
            if (typeOfSrc != null) {
                _gson.toJson(o, typeOfSrc, writer);
            } else {
                _gson.toJson(o, writer);
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (JsonIOException ex) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException("Could not write JSON: "
                    + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    // helpers

    private Charset getCharset(HttpHeaders headers) {
        if (headers != null && headers.getContentType() != null
                && headers.getContentType().getCharSet() != null) {
            return headers.getContentType().getCharSet();
        }
        return DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    }

}
```

Get request method in **SocialGraphUI.java**. There is object test and method allNodes, which returns list of objects of class Node and allEdges returns list of objects of class Edge.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getNodesAndEdges(ModelMap model) {

      model.addAttribute("nodes", test.allNodes);
      model.addAttribute("edges", test.allEdges);
      return "index";
   }
```

I get these error messages:

```
    type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet SocialGraphUI threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet SocialGraphUI threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcUriComponentsContributor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1043cc94' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] while setting bean property 'handlerAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1043cc94': Cannot create inner bean 'com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter#0' of type [com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter] while setting bean property 'messageConverters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter] for bean with name 'com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SocialGraphUI-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1043cc94': Cannot create inner bean 'com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter#0' of type [com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter] while setting bean property 'messageConverters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter] for bean with name 'com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SocialGraphUI-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter] for bean with name 'com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SocialGraphUI-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1325)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.converter.GsonMessageConverter
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:247)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1346)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1317)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.
```

Comment: Where is your class: GsonMessageConverter located? did you create the example package?

Comment: @rhinds thank you, you are right i used wrong package name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem here could be the duplicate `mvc:annotation-driven` declaration.

But anyway, [Spring 4.1 introduced Gson support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.1.html#_web_improvements) so that makes it way easier for you to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="cz.ario.socialgraphui.controller" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter" />
      <!-- other HttpMessageConverters you need here -->
      <!-- Also: why adding Jackson's MessageConverter? Gson should pick JSON serialization in this case -->
    </mvc:message-converters>
  </mvc:annotation-driven>


  <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/styles/" />

</beans>
```

Same thing with a JavaConfig example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("cz.ario.socialgraphui.controller")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
      converters.add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
      // ...
    }  

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/scripts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**").addResourceLocations("/styles/");
    }
}
```

Note: you should (almost) never use versioned XSDs in your XML configuration files - [see this SO question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version/20900801#20900801).

Comment: Thank you for this beneficial answer. I will award my bounty in 20 hours (can't do that earlier).