# spring xml configuration difference between spring-beans-3.1.xsd and spring-beans.xsd

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

what is the differences between

`http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd`

and

`http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd`

Because currently I almost done a Spring MVC(Java based server-side) project, and my last step is to apply my previous Spring Security Login sample to it. The Spring Security sample works flawlessly before I start my project.

Then, I realised both links above and I bump into ugly exceptions after applying my Spring Security sample.

My Spring MVC project is using this `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd` and my Spring Security was using this `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring configuration XML schema: with or without version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version)

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the version from the `.xsd` the XML schema that is used will be fetched from the spring jar dependencies that your project is using, and this is the right way to go.

Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version) it explains it in more detail