# SAXParseException, the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, xsd, spring-security-oauth2

Here is the header of my `spring-security.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<b:beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  

         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd  ">
```

When starting the server, I am prompted this error :

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4:  Failed to read
>   schema document 
>   'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd',
>   because  1) could not find the document;  2) the document could not be
>   read;  3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema/>.

My thoughts on this :

1. The link is valid and the document exists
2. I can read it and I can even reproduce this error if I place this xsd on my local classpath. So it's not a networking issue.
3. That's right, the file is starting by `<xs:schema>` instead of `<xsd:schema>`. But the source looks legit.

Why do I get this error and how can I get rid of it ?

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Just take a spring-mvc minimal example like this http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/ or https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/tree/master/src/main . Then, include the five libraries listed with the version in the schemaLocation. Finally, add the almost-empty spring-security.xml provided in the applicationContext.xml. Do not forget to close the <beans> tag. Start this application on a tomcat/jboss/jetty server.

Comment: Fun fact, I downloaded locally spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd, edited all occurences ofl "xs:" prefixes into "xsd:" and changed the 6th line of "xsi:schemaLocation" to "classpath:spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd" and it works. But I am no longer using the official xsd. So it is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Spring XSDs are normally also in the JARs, and the mapping of the URL in your schemaLocation is further mapped to an XSD file of your spring-security-oauth2-x.y.z.jar by the spring-security-oauth2-x.y.z.jar\META-INF\spring.schemas. Please check your JAR, perhaps the XSD is missing or the mapping is defect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change all your schema locations to use version-less URIs, those XSDs are embedded in Spring JARs.

Because you're using versioned links to XSDs, your application breaks if it can't find that particular version on classpath.

[See this SO answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version/20900801#20900801).