# schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring- beans-4.1.5.xsd

Tags: spring, web.xml

I get an error in spring-dispatcher.xml in eclipse as given below.

```
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-
 beans-4.1.5.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root 
 element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

I have latest spring libraries...

```
spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-context-support-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.1.5.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-context-support-4.1.5.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.5.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.5.RELEASE-sources.jar
```

spring-dispatcher.xml as given below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

It would be great if I get some help... The posts with same subject did not help me to resolve this.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The error is because it could not find the xsd. Try doing the below which is using a specific version 4.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

Or if you don't mention a version, it will try to use the latest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE beans>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

Comment: Using version-less schemas is strongly recommended, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version/20900801#20900801

Comment: I've got the similar problem. I didn't use any version. It worked fine.

Comment: I had the same problem, this fixed it for me. I am using Netbeans. :)

Comment: @HarshalPatil, You are welcome. Anything to help others.

Comment: I have the same problem and it got solved once I mentioned the version to xsd. Thanks minion!

Comment: It works for me when you start the server while you have connected to internet.

Comment: Thanks, working fine for me. But a small mistake is here. Instead of ```xmlns:context="http://www.springframework/schema/context"```, it should be ```xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"```.

Comment: Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 67; Element type "beans" must be declared.

Answer (score 4):

*From Cosmina I. - Pivotal Certified Professional Spring Developer Exam A Study Guide - 2017*

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
```

> A recommended (best) practice is to use this, since the version will
>   be correctly identified from the Spring dependency version in the
>   project. Also, the other advantage is that you can upgrade the Spring
>   version you are using, and the new definition specifications will be
>   automatically supported in your configuration files without your
>   having to modify them

Answer (score 2):

There is no such xsd in any Spring jar :
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.5.xsd

Spring xsd for Spring 4.1.x can be referenced by :
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
or better :
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

The correspondance between the URL and the real location inside each spring jar can be found in META-INF/spring.schemas, so the "version less" URL will still work when u upgrade Spring.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it went away by adding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

to spring-dispatcher.xml and then running update maven project.

Comment: I add <!DOCTYPE xml> after the <?xml...>

Answer (score 2):

Belive me or not, this may be a maven problem if you're using it and things ended up like this from nothing. I know this may not be your case, but if so, please update your maven project. **If you're using Eclipse IDE:**

1. Right click on the project name.
2. Maven.
3. Update Project...

Again, this **may** be your case. It worked for me doing this. This can work also to anybody else who is on the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me

```
    <beans  xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have enroled for spring course on udemy. I followed every step that my instructor show me to do.
So if you are using spring mvc and hibernate you may encounter this error
Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd' etc for:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/> and <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" /> elements
```

in my spring configuration file i had these two urls

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
```

in xsi:schemaLocation, which i replaced with

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
```

Actually visit these two sites
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/ and http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/
and just added the latest version of spring-mvc and spring-tx i.e, spring-mvc-4.2.xsd  and  spring-tx-4.2.xsd as shown above.

In my opinion specifying version no explicitly is a good practice.
It worked for me, hope this works for you too.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried modifying the xml as mentioned in the other solutions but none of them worked for me. In the end I tried opening the schema location file on a web browser but it wouldn't connect either (even though internet was working fine). Was the spring framework server down?

Turns out the Internet Security software that we use had to be turned **on** to access this site. So try opening the schema file in a web browser to verify that the URL is correct and that you can connect to it especially if the configuration was working fine previously.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it was giving the similar error for http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring.xsd file. Finally it was a missing jar in the application. I added the below dependency in my gradle file and that solved the problem

```
compile group: 'org.mybatis', name: 'mybatis-spring', version: '2.0.0'
```

So it could be a similar dependency or a spring jar missing in your application

Answer (score 0):

Using Version-less dependencies is appreciated. Find my code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <bean "class name goes here"> </bean>
</beans>
```