# Spring XML Schema issue

Tags: java, spring, xsd

below is the sample xml which is used in my spring project spring.xml

I want to remove spring version example spring-integration-xml-4.1.xsd
should replace with spring-integration-xml.xsd

But when tried for
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd
internet return spring intetegration 1.0 xsd it should return new schema
which is 4.1 s in my xml tags are based on 4.1 so its not working if i
add only spring-integration-xml.xsd

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd">

Like http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml-4.1.xsd
need to remove version 4.1
```

Comment: Why you want to remove it?

Comment: i do not want to specify spring version in the xml

Answer (score 0):

You should (almost) always refer to versionless XSDs in your XML configuration files; Spring will pick up the version included in the Spring JARs automatically.

See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20900801/22982).