# Spring MVC The matching wildcard is strict error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a program in spring mvc but getting an error. Here is the program

index.jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="false"/>
    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        omit-xml-declaration="true" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="welcome">Welcome Guest</a>
</body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

HelloController.java

```
package java4s;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java4s.EmployeeService;
@Controller
public class HelloController {  

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService emp_service;

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
        public ModelAndView helloWorld(@ModelAttribute("userForm") Employee employee, ModelMap model) {

            String message =  "Welcome to Java4s.com Spring MVC 4.1.1 Sessions";
                   message += "<br>You Did it....!";
                   List<String> professionList = new ArrayList();
                    professionList.add("Developer");
                    professionList.add("Designer");
                    professionList.add("IT Manager");
                    model.put("professionList", professionList);
            return new ModelAndView("welcomePage", "welcomeMessage", new Employee());
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/addemployee", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
    public ModelAndView submitForm(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("userForm") Employee employee/*, BindingResult errors*/) {

            /*if(errors.hasErrors())
            {
                model.addAttribute("studenterrors", "Errorsssss");
            }*/
            //System.out.println(student.getBirthdate());
            //model.addAttribute("studenterrors", "Errorsssss");
            model.addAttribute("username", employee.getUsername());
            model.addAttribute("password", employee.getPassword());
            model.addAttribute("birthdate", employee.getBirthdate());
            model.addAttribute("email", employee.getEmail());
            model.addAttribute("professionList", employee.getProfession());
            model.addAttribute("userForm", new Employee());

            emp_service.saveData(employee);
            return new ModelAndView("RegisterSuccess",model);
    }

}
```

EmployeeServiceImpl.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package java4s;

import java4s.Employee;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

/**
 *
 * @author Harshit Shrivastava
 */
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void saveData(Employee employee)
    {

        String query = "INSERT INTO EmployeeInfo(userid,username,firstname,lastname,mobileno,emailid,password,profession) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);


    }
}
```

welcome-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">

    <context:component-scan base-package="java4s" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="EmployeeService" class="java4s.EmployeeServiceImpl" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:IM"
    p:username="user"
    p:password="pass" />
</beans>
```

Whenever I submit the form, I get this error.
Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 14 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/welcome-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 27; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your xml to have `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd` as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="java4s" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="EmployeeService" class="java4s.EmployeeServiceImpl" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:IM"
    p:username="user"
    p:password="pass" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for version-less definition (see the xml below).
Spring is determining the schema to use based on the META-INF/spring.schemas in every spring jar.
Make sure you do not mix spring versions and do not have your own META-INF/spring.schemas in the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    >

    <context:component-scan base-package="java4s" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="EmployeeService" class="java4s.EmployeeServiceImpl" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:IM"
    p:username="user"
    p:password="pass" />
</beans>
```

See also [Spring configuration XML schema: with or without version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version) 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html