# Spring xsd versions, along with release?

Tags: spring

Seems like spring xsd versions go only to version 4.3 while version 5.0 is released?

If I am using Spring 5 should i continue to use 4.3 XSD in my bean defenition?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
                        https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-2.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        https://www.springframework.org/schema/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        https://www.springframework.org/schema/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">
```

This spring schema location
https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/

shows that latest XSD version is 4.3

```
[TXT] spring-beans-2.0.xsd    2018-01-23 08:42   38K  
[TXT] spring-beans-2.5.xsd    2018-01-23 08:42   41K  
[TXT] spring-beans-3.0.xsd    2018-01-23 08:42   41K  
[TXT] spring-beans-3.1.xsd    2018-01-23 08:42   42K  
[TXT] spring-beans-3.2.xsd    2018-01-23 08:42   43K  
[TXT] spring-beans-4.0.xsd    2018-01-23 08:42   42K  
[TXT] spring-beans-4.1.xsd    2018-01-23 08:42   43K  
[TXT] spring-beans-4.2.xsd    2018-01-23 08:42   43K  
[TXT] spring-beans-4.3.xsd    2018-01-23 08:42   43K  
[TXT] spring-beans.xsd        2018-01-23 08:42   43K
```

Comment: It has been recommended for some years now to always use the version-less XSD.

Comment: when i swith to version-less XSD this is the error i get:    The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring configuration XML schema: with or without version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version)